# logging ONLY effected rows in sql update procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a procedure that updates x amount of rows in a table. I have created a log table that will have records of all the updated rows. So each time i run my procedure and it effect eg. 5 rows,  these 5 rows will then be inserted into my log table.

this is my procedure:

```
UPDATE dbo.ImportAdvTemp
SET dbo.ImportAdvTemp.DeliveryAdrID = dbo.ImportAdvTemp_IMPORTED.DeliveryAdrID
FROM dbo.ImportAdvTemp, dbo.ImportAdvTemp_IMPORTED
WHERE 
    ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp.DeliveryName, '') = ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp_IMPORTED.DeliveryName, '') AND
    ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp.DeliveryStreet,'') = ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp_IMPORTED.DeliveryStreet, '') AND
    ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp.DeliveryHouseNumber, '') = ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp_IMPORTED.DeliveryHouseNumber, '') AND
    ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp.DeliverySubCity, '') = ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp_IMPORTED.DeliverySubCity, '') AND
    ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp.DeliveryPostCode, '') = ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp_IMPORTED.DeliveryPostCode, '') AND
    ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp.DeliveryCity, '') = ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp_IMPORTED.DeliveryCity, '') AND
    ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp.DeliveryCountry, '') = ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp_IMPORTED.DeliveryCountry, '') AND
    ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp.DeliveryCustomer, '') = ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp_IMPORTED.DeliveryCustomer, '') AND
    ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp.DeliveryAlias, '') = ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp_IMPORTED.DeliveryAlias, '') AND
    ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp.DeliveryNote, '') = ISNULL(dbo.ImportAdvTemp_IMPORTED.DeliveryNote, '') AND
    dbo.ImportAdvTemp.toManualProc = 1 and dbo.ImportAdvTemp.Closed = 0 and(dbo.ImportAdvTemp.DeliveryAdrID IS NULL or dbo.ImportAdvTemp.PickupAdrID IS NULL or dbo.ImportAdvTemp.DeliveryAdrID = 0 or dbo.ImportAdvTemp.PickupAdrID = 0)
```

I need to figure out which rows are effected and then use data from that row to insert in my log table. I have read about using a cursors, is that the only way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about sqlserver, but in Oracle the most straightfoward solution would be an UPDATE trigger, which inserts into a log table and I am sure you can do the same in sqlserver.

The nice thing about a trigger is that it stays out of your way in the code, which does the real work (the update). You can disable or alter the trigger without messing with the main code, and it will only affect the logging aspect.

As a side note, You may need to consider the situtation, that a row is updated (because it matches the WHERE clause), but old and new values are the same. Do you want this logged or not, or do you prevent this from happening by writing an appropritate WHERE clause? Do you want old, new vor both values logged? You will have to answer this question regardless of the logging implementation.

Comment: I only want to log the row which is updated. This procedure is gonna be used to auto validate records. I will have a catalog table. This table will contain manually validated rows. And if a row is inserted again with identical vsalues, the user wont have to validate it, it will be validated automatically. So how would a trigger "know" when a row og multiple rows are effected ?

Comment: You need a FOR EACH ROW trigger. It will fire once for each affected row. However, I am talking Oracle here, and I don't know if SQLSERVER has FOR EACH ROW triggers.

Comment: I don't think so. The trigger is attached to a table and would be independant from your procedure, i.e. it would log updates, whether they are initiated by your procedure or from somewhere else.

Comment: its because i have to log all the info from the other tables. So i need the column data to insert into my log table.

Comment: Are you sure you have to do this? Wouldn't it be enough to log the changes of the table which was really updated? I you need column values from other tables you can always join your log with these tables

Comment: i think were on the same page. I only want to log the row were the update has been made. so if table2.DeliveryAdrID is updated, then i have to log information from table2

Comment: Yes this is a trigger. I've done exactly what you are talking about in SQL Server. Look up triggers. You can set them up to be any combination of insert or update. You could create an update trigger that would log what records get changed. One word of caution - a trigger is only fired once per update command. Make sure you cycle through all the records. Also make sure the trigger is very fast otherwise you will see your system slow down on updates.
This will record any changes made by anybody anywhere - not just the records in the stored proc.